# Why don't Bertolt and Reiner break the city walls?

Tags: attack-on-titan

It's noted throughout the anime that there are titans that live within the walls and are what have been stopping the regular titans from being able to break into the city. Bertolt can kick walls down as he proves multiple times, Annie can even destroy the walls and she's the weakest of the special titans.

So why haven't Bertolt and Reiner broken down all of the walls up to this point?

Comment: Since I don't read the manga much I'll leave my post as a comment but as a warning. The full details behind the special titans and their goal is a very prominent plot point in the current arcs in the manga which have not been revealed yet to the anime community. I strongly recommend that you read it for yourself and take in the full experience. But if you REALLY want to know I urge the answerer to use spoiler tags.

Comment: I too recommended the answerer to use spoiler tags.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The main reason is that wall is very thick, due to

> titans inside the wall

according to chapter 33 of manga.

Female Specie was able to breach outer layer, but to completely bust through wall, you need to get through inner layer.

Armored Titan and Colossus are focused on gates for same reasons - gates are weakest part of walls formation.